# Как в aiogram сделать inline кнопку для одного пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, callback, inline

К примеру:
~Пользователь_1 отправил сообщение "Бизнес"
~Бот прислал меню бизнеса пользователя с инлайн кнопками (собрать прибыль, оплатить налоги и т.п.)
~Пользователь_1 нажимает на инлайн кнопку и сообщение редактируется
Если кнопку нажмёт любой другой пользователь, то выскочит сообщение "Это не твоя кнопка"

Мой код:

```
@dp.callback_query()
async def InlineSystem(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    id_tg_user = callback_query.from_user.id
    if callback_query.message.from_user.id == id_tg_user:
        if callback_query.data == "BUSINESS_PROFIT":
            await BUSINESS_PROFIT(callback_query)
        elif callback_query.data == "BUSINESS_TAX"
            await BUSINESS_TAX(callback_query)
    elif callback_query.message.from_user.id != id_tg_user:
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback_query.id, text=f"Это не твоя кнопка")
```

p.s в BUSINESS_PROFIT и BUSINESS_TAX сообщения редактируются

Дело в том, что когда сообщение редактируется, то в callback.message.from_user.id ставится id самого бота и после нажатия на кнопку у Пользователя_1 выскакивает сообщение "Это не твоя кнопка".
Проверял callback_query через print(), он не содержит информации о Пользователе_1.
Как реализовать не понимаю.

Comment: Вместо `callback_query.message.from_user.id` надо использовать `callback_query.from_user.id`

Comment: callback_query.from_user.id даёт айди пользователя, который нажал на кнопку

Comment: Записывайте в callback_data id первоначального пользователя и сравнивайте с ним

Comment: @Unicod Да, `callback_query.message` же отсылает к сообщению, к которому прикреплена inline-клавиатура

Comment: @CausonQ, возможно это ответ на мой вопрос, можете уточнить, как это сделать?

Comment: При создании кнопки записываете id, типа такого: `text='bla1', callback_data=f"bla2_{message.from_user.id}"`. А потом, при обработке разделяете callback_data сплитом и записываете куда-нибудь этот id. Или используйте [фабрику коллбэков](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/callback_data.html)

Comment: Вроде как, если другой пользователь нажимает на кнопку, то бот никак не реагирует

Comment: @NTA если Пользователь, который вызвал это сообщение нажмёт на кнопку то, после редактирования сообщения ботом, при повторной попытке нажать на кнопку ему будет писать "Это не твоя кнопка", в этом вся проблема. Кнопку получается сделать для одного пользователя, но после редактирования сообщения она перестаёт работать корректно

Comment: @CausonQ благодарю, прописал создание клавиатуры везде где она используется и пока что всё работает чётко (неделю ломал голову над этим вопросом, пролетала мысль добавить id в call.data, но почему то так и не сделал)